# Stream object from MinIO using command line (mcli)

Tags: command-line, stream, minio

I'm using the command line tool of MinIO ([mcli](https://github.com/minio/mc)). I want to download a file/folder and directly pipe it into zip and something like

```
mcli get myinstance/output/file.csv | zip myfile.zip -
```

but I only find options to pipe a stream TO MinIO not FROM. Is there something like that without having an intermediate step of saving the data to the harddrive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try with this command mcli cat alias/bucket/object | zip myfile.zip -
?

Comment: Thx. That would solve the usecase of getting a single file. But dumping a whole folder into a zip via `mcli` seems not to be possible.